# How to make a struts2 project an executable Application

Tags: struts2, installation, executable, war

I have developed a Struts2 Project using Apache server and MySQL database.

Is it possible to make this application an `executable` application so that i do not need to give JDK, Apache and MySQL separately to the user. The installer could install all these 3 itself.

Also can i make this so that only a single user can use this application. How Please Tell.

Comment: Use a Virtual Machine, make a snapshot, give out the snapshot. The only software needed by the user will be the virtualization software (VMWare Player free for example).

Comment: @gauravishere What that mean is that you you should install the application, MySQL and every other software that u need and distribute the snapshot. Hope you understand this. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Usually a Web Application has a central server (with at least: a Java Virtual Machine, a Web Server / Application Server, a Database, and the Web Application contanining the Java code), and all the client computers use their browsers to connect to it.

The kind of application that seems to arise from your description is a monolitic one, like a GUI App made in Swing or in Visual Basic; you install it in the clients, and each one has a copy of each component. If you install it 20 times, you will have 20 database, 20 copies of the files, etc...
Even in client-server applications, with centralized database and distributed code, the problems were always client-related; you can't know if the system were you are automatically installing a database, an JDK etc... already has that software, maybe in other versions, or has the environment variables messed up etc. When you need to update the software, or to tune up the system, you need to be physically log to that pc, remotely or by person. This are some of the reasons that led to the choice of preferring Web Applications to distributed applications.

If you need to craft a "package" of your application to be installed in one click by a dumb user (let's say, a portable version of your application, to let your PM perform some Demo in remote locations, or to give it to the big boss to let him see it), you should really evaluate the possibility of creating a Virtual Machine.

A Virtual Machine is a big file (on a hard disk, or read by an USB key, etc) that, once *mounted* by a Virtualization Software (usually the same software that created the Virtual Machine), will run an entire new OS inside a window of your guest OS.

The leading software to do this is [VMWare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) ([the Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Player) is free and cross-platform), alternatively you can use [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_box).

Then, you need to

- download VMWare Player
- download the ISO of your favourite Linux distribution (I hope you don't use Windows as server)
- create a, let's say, 10GB partition for your Linux distribution with VMWare Player, and mount it
- plug the ISO with something like (the free edition of) [Daemon Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_Tools)
- install the Linux distribution
- install and configure all the software you need there (Apache, MySQL, your favourite browsers, etc; JVM usually is already there)
- install your web application

Then you will have a physical file with a complete Linux OS inside, with all the needed software already tuned up: just distribute this file to Windows, Mac or Linux users, they will only need the VMWare Player installed to run your file and access (their copy of) your application inside the Linux OS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrea. But this will make it a very hectic task and a very large file will need to be delivered, as you said. Is not there any soft way to do this. Whether it will be feasible/good if i deliver Apache, MySQL and the application separately. If yes then how(in what format e.g. WAR/JAR/EXE) my application will be delivered.

Comment: Also tell me how can i prevent user to further distribute the copy of my application.

Comment: You can't, if you give them the source code (the .class can be decompiled ;). Then you should really use all on your server, and open it to their browser: go for a VPN, so noone will steal anything from you and you will white-list the visitors by granting their IP on-demand when needed.

Comment: (and this is a Network Administrator job, not a Developer one...)